# 12v dc motor speed control using pwm and h bridge

Tags: pwm

I was wondering if yous could lend me a hand with my college project. 
I have been asked to control the speed of a dc 12v motor.
It must go in forward and reverse. 
See i know i need to make an h bridge. And would like to use a 555 timer to create the PWM. 
Would someone be able to direct me to which components i will require?
I was thinking of getting a 555 timer, and a h bridge driver but do i need a micro controller to control this. I really need some help lol.
I know you can make an h bridge with transistors but do i need to use mosfets.
 The 12v dc motor rating is 80.16W, 8311 rpm. 92.13mNm.
Any assitance would be greatly apreaciated

Comment: If the motor were 80.15 W I could think of a few solutions, but nothing comes to mind for 80.16 W.

Answer (score 4):

This is best done with a microcontroller.  Give the 555 timer back to the museum you got it from.

You are right in that you need a H bridge.  Nowadays, the logic of when to pulse it high, low, and open is performed in a microcontroller.  Many micros have PWM hardware for just this purpose, some even with complementary outputs for controlling the 4 switches of the H bridge separately.  If you don't know where to start, check out the dsPIC line from Microchip.

Back in the pleistocene this might have been done with a 555 timer somehow controlling a H bridge.  You could kludge up something like this today too, but the result would be more complicated electrically, much harder to tune or control, and less repeatable from unit to unit.

There is some up-front learning time with the microcontroller solution.  Since you are apparently studying electrical engineering, this is something you absolutely must learn anyway.  Even though it may seem hard this time if you aren't already comfortable with microcontrollers, you're going to have to learn them.  The sooner you do, the sooner you will have the benefit of being able to apply them when appropriate, and the more experience you will have gotten by the time you look for a real job.  Leave 555 timers to old-timers and hobbyists.  Their place in modern commercial products is vanishingly small.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Ill give you the down low. I need to make a circuit (just prototype on breadboard). The motor controls a hoist that moves up and down( hence the forward and reverse movement required). I have built the mechanical side of the hoist ( project).could you help me with a list of components i will require. As in which transistors or h bridge driver. Any resistors and all. Do i require a potentiometer?

Comment: @Genj: So it seems you're a mechanical engineering student?  In that case, get a EE student to do the motor driver and controller has *his* project.

Comment: Also im an apprentice maintenance technician. Ive just started studying electronics. Ive studied electrical engineering. Now in my second year it has moved onto electronics, so im anot of a newbie in the electronics world. Again any help or a push in thr right direction would be appriciated